# Datatables dynamically change on row but data object not change ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

we coding a quotation form for our company and want to add products a datatable and changing value on it. After change data we send to controller but they same the first time. Here is datatable structure.

```
var selectedProduct = $('#selectedproduct').DataTable({
            "columns": [
                  {
                      "orderable": false,
                      "data": "IsConfirm",
                  },
                 { "orderable": false, "data": "Product.Id" },
                 { "orderable": false, "data": "Product.Name" },
                 { "orderable": false, "data": "Product.Description" },
                 {
                     "orderable": false,
                     "data": "Quantity",
                     "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                         return '<td width="100px"><input class="touchspinquantity" type="text" value="' + data + '" name="quantity"></td>';
                     }
                 },
                 { "orderable": false, "data": "Product.SalePrice" },
                 {
                     "orderable": false,
                     "data": "Discount",
                     "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                         return '<td width="100px"><input class="touchspindiscount" type="text" value="' + data + '" name="discount"></td>';
                     }
                 },
                 { "orderable": false, "data": "Product.Currency" },
                 { "orderable": false, "data": null, "defaultContent": '' },
                 {
                     "orderable": false,
                     "data": null,
                     "defaultContent": '<button id="deleteproduct" class="btn btn-warning btn-circle" type="button"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>'
                 },

            ],
            "createdRow": function (row, data, index) {
                if (data.IsConfirm) {
                    $('td', row).eq(0).html('<input type="checkbox" checked class="i-checks" name="input[]">');
                }
                else {
                    $('td', row).eq(0).html('<input type="checkbox" class="i-checks" name="input[]">');
                }
            },
            "searching": false,
            "paging": false,
            "bInfo": false,
            "ordering": false
        });
```

Here is how to get data

```
var datat = table.fnGetData();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem but maybe that's not good way.
Here is the solve

```
var rows = table.fnGetNodes();
            var arr = [[]];
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                var detaildata = [];
                var cells = rows[i].cells;
                detaildata[0] = cells[0].childNodes["0"].checked;
                detaildata[1] = cells[1].innerText;
                detaildata[2] = cells[2].innerText;
                detaildata[3] = cells[3].innerText;
                detaildata[4] = cells[4].firstChild.childNodes[1].value;
                detaildata[5] = cells[5].innerText;
                detaildata[6] = cells[6].firstChild.childNodes[1].value;
                detaildata[7] = cells[7].innerText;
                detaildata[8] = cells[8].innerText;

                arr[[i]] = detaildata;
                //var select = cells[0].children[0].value;
                //if (cells[0].children[0].checked) {
                //    select = cells[0].children[0].value;
                //} else {
                //    select = 'off';
                //}
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to redraw the datatable after the updation

```
selectedProduct.draw();
```

Comment: not work :( problem is my sending object is not changing after column edit